# how to use etcd in service discovery?

Tags: etcd, etcd3

I am beginner for etcd
my purpose is the follow
1.service register itself after service start
2.client find service and invoke service

**the follow code show test how to find service and invoke it**

```
func ClientTestService() {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   []string{endpoint},
        DialTimeout: time.Second * 5,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("connect etcd err:", err.Error())
        return
    }

    defer cli.Close()
    r := &naming.GRPCResolver{Client: cli}
    b := grpc.RoundRobin(r)

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(service_name, grpc.WithBalancer(b), grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("dial err:", err.Error())
        return
    }

    defer conn.Close()
    c := calc.NewCalcClient(conn)
    req := calc.CalcRequest{IResult: 1, SResult: "req"}
    resp, err := c.CalcResult(context.Background(), &req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("calc err:", err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(resp.IResult, resp.SResult)
}
```

console output "calc err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = there is no address available"  after execute `resp, err := c.CalcResult(context.Background(), &req)`
it means that resolver can't find the address of service from the service name
i guess there have two possible
1. call service need start etcd "proxy service"  or "gateway" first
2. need to get service address from service name by manual

**the follow code show register service**

```
func RegisterService(w *sync.WaitGroup) {
    w.Add(1)
    defer func() {
        w.Done()
    }()

    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   []string{endpoint},
        DialTimeout: time.Second * 5,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("etcd err:", err)
        return
    }

    cli.Delete(cli.Ctx(), service_name)
    r := &naming.GRPCResolver{Client: cli}
    for _, addr := range GetLocalAddrs() {
        service_node := addr + ":" + strconv.Itoa(port)
        err = r.Update(cli.Ctx(), service_name, gn.Update{Op: gn.Add, Addr: service_node})
        log.Println("register node :", service_name, service_node, err)
    }
}
```

My understanding is that function "ClientTestService" connect etcd server and resolve the service name to service address and invoke service by balance
but when i debug this code and then find it just invoke etcd by balance,
is there function in etcd for my need ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The error happens when the client code invokes the server method. This is what I got from etcd log:

`2017-08-13 20:04:22.571628 I | etcdserver/api/v3rpc: transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 127.0.0.1:2379->127.0.0.1:49150: read: connection reset by peer]`

Comment: @srxf This is etcd v3.2 in the window system on a bug
you can use the last version of the etcd

Comment: i'm using the latest version of etcd v3.2.5 running on a x64 ubuntu linux box. have you made it work already?

Comment: @srxf yes, it works fine for me

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, I would really appreciate it if you would share the code :)

Comment: @srxf ,question content has the code, my code doesn't have any problem, just a bug of etcd cause this issue

Answer (score -2):

Try add grpc.WithBlock() for Dial, like this:

```
grpc.Dial(service_name, grpc.WithBalancer(b), grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock() )
```